Using libx265 and dash, there is sound, no video
ffmpeg -i /v.webm -preset slow -map_metadata -1 -profile:v main -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 \
        -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
        -map v:0 -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144,fps=30" -minrate:v:0 90k  -maxrate:v:0 150k -bufsize:v:0 60k \
        -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
        -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
        -dash_segment_type mp4 \
        -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 \
        -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
        -f dash /dash.mpd

Everything works, I changed the codec from libx264 to libx265. As a result, there is sound, but no video. At the end of the conversion I get this error.
Segment durations differ too much, enable use_timeline and use_template, or keep a stricter keyframe interval


ffmpeg -i /v.webm -preset ultrafast -movflags +faststart -profile:v main -c:v libx265 -x264opts "keyint=24:min-keyint=8:no-scenecut" -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 \
        -map 0:a -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
        -map v:0 -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144,fps=30" -minrate:v:0 90k -maxrate:v:0 150k -bufsize:v:0 60k \
        -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
        -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
        -dash_segment_type mp4 \
        -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 \
        -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
        -f dash /x1/dash.mpd

Doesn't work either, complains about -use_timeline

-use_timeline 1, The error is gone, but there is still no picture

ffmpeg -i /v.webm -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -x264opts "keyint=24:min-keyint=8:no-scenecut" -c:a libopus...

For fixing the warning "Segment durations differ too much", try replacing -keyint_min 250 -g 250 with -g 150. Each segment is 300 frames (10 seconds at 30fps), and GOP size 250 is not a multiple of 300. -g 150 applies 2 GOPs in each segment (just for testing). You also missed the video bitrate, add -b:v 120k for example.

I can’t link it to the bitrate... Please try my latest option. What's the matter, the main thing is not to tie it to the bitrate. Works with libx264...

Neither of the two options helps

Does video-only work?

Plays only sound, does not play video

Help is needed...

ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=384x216:r=30:d=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -shortest -profile:v main -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 150 -sc_threshold 0 -map 1:a -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 1 -ar 48000 -map 0:v -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144,fps=30" -b:v 120k -minrate:v:0 90k -maxrate:v:0 150k -bufsize:v:0 60k -init_seg_name "init-stream$RepresentationID$.$ext$" -media_seg_name "chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" -dash_segment_type mp4 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -f dash -movflags +faststart dash.mpd

Try synthetic audio and video. The mpd file is played fine with ffplay.
